# Splite string to text and integer

Tags: ruby, string

I wanna know if there is a quick way to solve the problem in ruby like example below

example
"t12" => text="t", value=12

"ad15" => text = "ad", value = 15

"acbds1687" => text = "acbds", value=1687

I think regular expression may can solve this but I am not sure about regular expression.

Comment: In your examples, there are no spaces in the strings.  Readers will assume that's a requirement, and that's not a problem.  If, however, you want a more general solution, now is the time to say so (by editing, giving additional examples of strings you are given and what you want to extract).

Comment: I have a string that combine with letter and integer and I want to split it. The problem is that it is closed to each other that hard to split and I don't want to count each string element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like below:

```
irb(main):001:0> "t12".split(/(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\d)/)
=> ["t", "12"]
```

Comment: Awesome :) Work like a charm

Answer (score 2):

If you give create a capture group it stays in the split, thus this code is pretty slick:

```
text, value = string.split(/(\d+)/)
```

or you can use the slice! method:

```
text  = 'sagasg125512'
value = text.slice!(/\d+/)
p text  #=> "sagasg"
p value #=> "125512"
```

Answer (score 1):

To parse the string into a hash like `{ :text => "t", :value => 12 }`:

```
def parse (string)
  matchdata = string.match(/([a-zA-Z]+)([\d]+)/)
  text = matchdata[1]
  value = matchdata[2].to_i

  return { text: text, value: value }
end
```

To parse the string into an array like `["t", 12]`:

```
def parse (string)
  matchdata = string.match(/([a-zA-Z]+)([\d]+)/)
  text = matchdata[1]
  value = matchdata[2].to_i

  return [text, value]
end
```